# Trying to get property of non-object when reading column from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to read a column in mysql with php and mysqli, but I get this error. `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

PHP

```
<?php
  $db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
  global $db;
  $subscribers = $db->query('SELECT * FROM subscribers');
  foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
    $name = $subscriber->name; // name is the name of the column
    echo $name;
  }
?>
```

MYSQL

```
Name    Type
ID      int(10)
name    varchar(50)
email   varchar(150)
confirmed   varchar(50)
date    datetime
```

What am I missing, to tell the truth did not understood well the objects chapter.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty , but is there anyway to do it in a foreach?

Comment: You need to fetch the record as object using loop u need to get them since the cursor pointer will be set to first record in the record set.

Comment: you'd better learn how to follow manual instead of pointless "hunches" like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should fetch the result:

```
<?php
      $db = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
      global $db;
      $subscribers = $db->query('SELECT * FROM subscribers');

      while ($subscriber = $subscribers->fetch_object()) {
          $name = $subscriber->name; // name is the name of the column
          echo $name;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$db->query` returns a result object which can't be directly iterated over. Try something like this:

```
$subscribers = $db->query('SELECT * FROM subscribers');
while ($subscriber = $subscribers->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $subscriber['name']; // name is the name of the column
    echo $name;
}
```